# DB design help in approve reject workflow

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have an issue for designing a Db in SQL. I have following scenarios.

1. There are many task
2. Each task has many questions
3. Each question has answers in the form of (yes/no/NA) only 3 answers (fixed).
4. These answers are responded by a (`level1`) user
5. After initial response, these response is received by '`level2`' users. '`level2`' contain many users but any user approval/reject only required from '`level2`'. Then it moves to next level
6. After '`level2`' user approval it is passed to '`level3`'. '`level3`' also has many users but only one user approval/rejection is required. Then it is finished
7. When it is rejected, re-submission requires from `level1 & level2` and workflow continues.

I have come up with following design. It is just a prototype

```
**User table**
uid
username

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Role Table** (level1,level2,level3 also it has admin,sub-admin and Normal Guest)
role id
Role Name

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**user-roles table**
uid
role id

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Question table**
Qid
Quest Name

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Task Table**
task id
task name

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Task-question table** (Each task has many questions). it will be created by admin
tqid
task id
Question_id

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Question-Answer-Response Table**
AnsId
tqid
Response (contains yes/no/NA)
Userid ( user who answered)
```

Now, level 2 and level 3 apprval/rejection should happen and I am stuck at this point.